# Python: no module named datetime?

Tags: python

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Python: 2.7.6

My installation of Gourmet Recipe Manager suddenly stopped loading. When I run it in a terminal window, I get the following at the end of the traceback:

```
import datetime as dt
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

So far as I can tell, nothing has been changed and my Python installation is up to date. It simply quit working yesterday. I'd certainly appreciate a good approach to diagnose and fix this problem!

Update: thanks to all who replied!

Tim, I'm sorry if I asked this question in the wrong place. Please chalk it up to being a new guy simply following the links from the Ubuntu website.

TheSchwa, I tried your suggestion and got the same error message as above.

muru, the package seems to be installed, but I have no idea if it's installed/configured correctly. How might I find out?

I'm sorry for all the questions, but I'm an old RedHat guy who has been away from Linux for some time. All of the apt/dpkg stuff is new to me.

Comment: While this is (just) on topic here, you might get a better response on [so]. Also, I can't reproduce it. No errors at all, on the same set-up as you...

Comment: What happens if you try `import datetime` in the python interpreter? You can start the interpreter by opening a terminal and executing `python`. You can leave it with `Ctrl+d`.

Comment: According to `dpkg -S $(python -c "import datetime; print datetime.__file__")`, the datetime module is from the
`libpython2.7-stdlib` package. Is that package correctly installed? Can you try reinstalling it?

Comment: Okay, so the specific file is `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` do you have that file? Also do you see `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` listed in the output from `echo $(python -c "import sys; print sys.path")`? Btw the Stack Exchange system doesn't actually notify commenters when you edit your post; so at the very least always post a quick comment such as "Updated question with the info" so we get a notification telling us to check back :)

Comment: Updated question with the info. Thanks, TheSchwa! My answers are no and yes, respectively. Now, where can I get a new copy of datetime.x86_64-linux.gnu.so? :)

Comment: `sudo pip install datetime` for those left wondering.

Answer (score 89):

This just happened to me after the 14.10 update, and it seems to be because my virtual environments have old copies of `/usr/bin/python2.7` that — unlike the new binary — do not include `datetime` built-in, and so get an error when they cannot find it on disk anywhere. The new interpreter seems to import it without any file I/O (try running it under `strace` to check).

I fixed each virtual environment by activating it and running:

```
$ cp /usr/bin/python2.7 $(which python2.7)
```

Comment: Thanks but why is this necessary?  Breaking python on an upgrade is nasty stuff.

Comment: I tried the other answers on this page and they didn't work, but this one did.

Comment: Got `cp: '/usr/bin/python2.7' and '/usr/bin/python2.7' are the same file` but the error still exists

Comment: @Umair There might be something wrong with your `activate` script, in that case — normally, after activation, `which python2.7` will show the path to the environment's Python, not return the path to the system Python.

Comment: This also work with virtualenv installations

Answer (score 31):

You can just reinitialize the virtualenv by:

```
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
virtualenv .
```

Comment: Note that it should be `virtualenv .` instead of `virtualenv ,`

Comment: This answer seems better, than Brandon Rhodes's one.

Comment: If one uses the virtualenvwrapper can do `cd $VIRTUAL_ENV`.

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Cerin, I had the same problem, I just used a `sudo virtualenv .` to install the new Python executable, and then changed back the whole `$VIRTUAL_ENV` to the correct directory owner.

Answer (score 30):

If you're getting this trying to use letsencrypt after an upgrade, this solution worked for me [letsencrypt forums - Can't use auto import: error: no module named io/2345/3](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cant-use-letsencrypt-auto-importerror-no-module-named--io/2345/3)

I just had to delete this:

```
rm ~/.local/share/letsencrypt -R
```

Comment: I also had to `rm -rf /opt/eff.org` to make it work

Comment: removing /opt/eff.org fixed it

Comment: same for me ... /opt/eff.org

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally decided it must be the AWS CLI because I noticed that it had it's own python directory. So I uninstalled AWS CLI and reinstalled it and that fixed the problem:

`sudo pip uninstall awscli`

`sudo pip install awscli`

Answer (score 0):

As i found some changes in 14.04 so you need do this from root:

For datetime only:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
```

For all modules:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/audioop.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/audioop.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bsddb.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                        /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bsddb.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                           /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.x86_64-linux-gnu.so               /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/crypt.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                         /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/crypt.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_csv.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                          /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_csv.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes_test.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes_test.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/dbm.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                           /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/dbm.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fpectl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                        /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fpectl.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/future_builtins.x86_64-linux-gnu.so               /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/future_builtins.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hotshot.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hotshot.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                         /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/linuxaudiodev.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/linuxaudiodev.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                          /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.x86_64-linux-gnu.so               /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.x86_64-linux-gnu.so              /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/nis.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                           /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/nis.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/ossaudiodev.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/ossaudiodev.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/parser.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                        /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/parser.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                      /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                          /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_testcapi.x86_64-linux-gnu.so                     /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_testcapi.so
```

Also if you use virtual env copy

```
cp $(which python2.7) /opt/graphite/bin/python
```

to your env.

Comment: I upgraded to 14.04 and didn't need to do any symlink. Could you provide any evidence that messing the system libs like this is necessary and can't be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. I recreated my virtualenv and the issue went away. So if you're working with a virtualenv, you should recreate it.

However if you don't, I suppose that reinstalling your project will work. Don't touch any system libraries! It can work for the time being, but will potentially lead to issues with others.

Answer (score 0):

This happens after some Ubuntu upgrades. My favorite solution is

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages path/to/virtualenv/dir
```

This updates everything needed without removing the packages already installed.

If you have many virtualenvs to update, you can use `xargs`:

```
$ ls ~/directory/with/virtualenvs | xargs -L1 virtualenv --no-site-packages
```