# ImportError: No module named datetime upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AWS CLI

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, python, python-2.7, aws

I can't get the AWS CLI using python2.7 to work after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04LTS.  I've tried the suggestions from [This SO Question from 14.04 Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509283/python-no-module-named-datetime) with no luck.  I also uninstalled and reinstalled python2.7.  The error I get is `ImportError: No module named datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally decided it must be the AWS CLI because I noticed that it had it's own python directory.  So I uninstalled AWS CLI and reinstalled it and that fixed the problem:

`sudo pip uninstall awscli`

`sudo pip install awscli`